# jQuery script with wheel event works in Mozilla but not WebKit or Edge

Tags: jquery, firefox

Does anyone know why the following script works in Mozilla but not in WebKit or Edge?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const parent = $('.parent');
  const incrementAmount = 20;
  const minPosition = 1;
  const maxPosition = 10;

  parent.on('wheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const currentPosition = parseInt(parent.attr('data-position'));
    const scrollDistance = event.originalEvent.deltaY;

    if (scrollDistance % incrementAmount === 0) {
      let newPosition = currentPosition;

      if (scrollDistance < 0) {
        newPosition = Math.min(currentPosition + 1, maxPosition);
      } else {
        newPosition = Math.max(currentPosition - 1, minPosition);
      }

      parent.attr('data-position', newPosition);
    }
  });
});
```

Scrolling up/down in Firefox changes the data value. In other browsers the value is unchanged.

Comment: scrollDistance constant will give different results thru different browsers. Make sure you convert it to an INT before the if statement.